# JSON value gives undefined

Tags: javascript, electron

I have created an electron app that fetches a JSON value from https://complimentr.com/api. But, when you click the button to set the innerHTML value to the JSON value, it gives the dreaded 'undefined'.

```
// create a variable called url and set it to the url of the website
var url = "https://evilinsult.com/generate_insult.php?lang=en&type=json";
// create a variable called response and set it to the response of the get request
request(url, function(error, response, body){
  var data = JSON.parse(body);
  console.log(data.compliment);
  const btn = document.getElementById('button-1');

  btn.onclick = () => {
    document.body.innerHTML = data.compliment
  }
});
```

Is there any reason this isn't working? I am new at JavaScript so this could be an easy fix.

Comment: You're using the wrong URL. `evilinsult.com` returns insults, not compliments.

Comment: yeah, forgot to change the link lol

Comment: `console.log(error)` (before your `JSON.parse()` line), and hopefully that will tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It should be response.compliment not data.compliment

console.log(response.compliment);

Comment: Doesn't work for me, still prints undefined @mpt madhushan

Comment: Why do you think this? `data` is where the result of `JSON.parse(body)` is saved.

Comment: he mentioned `request(url, function(error, response, body)` that's why i told that

Comment: my bad :( didn't see ` var data = JSON.parse(body);`

Comment: So what is the solution? because ```data``` still gives undefined